problema para usar el codigo docker compose up
version: '6.0.16'

services:

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: ${MONGO_USER}
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MONGO_PASS}
    volumes:
      - ./mongo:/data/db
    ports:
      - 27017:27017

al querer correr el comando docker compose up- me dice que mi version es obsoleta probé muchas versiones y ninguna me sirve

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! pone la traza del error completa
